# keytool + openssl - convert JKS to PKCS12 loses the Subject Alternate Name

Tags: java, ssl, keytool

I've searched other questions and found very helpful information but I couldn't quite find an answer to the specific problem I have here.

The basic question/problem is:  I have a Java Keystore in .JKS format and I need to convert it (or at least the private key) to PKCS12.  The JKS keystore contains a certificate entry with a SAN (Subject Alternate Name) but when converting to .p12 the resulting PKCS12 file does not contain the SAN on the key.

Java 8, latest OpenSSL as of 11/9/2017.

My ultimate goal is to generate a CSR using keytool and then use that CSR to generate a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL.  (This is for internal company use so we do not need a signed certificate here.)

Steps I have taken:

First I used keytool to generate a new keypair in my JKS keystore as follows (domain names/hostnames/IPs have been changed):

keytool -genkeypair -keystore my.keystore -dname "CN=hostname, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown" -keyalg RSA -alias mydomain -ext SAN=dns:host.domain.com,ip:1.2.3.4

I verified with "keystore -v -list -keystore my.keystore:

```
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
DNSName: host.domain.com
IPAddress: 1.2.3.4
```

OK, so far so good.  I next create a certificate request using the same -ext command option and I verify that it worked:

keytool -printcertreq -file my.csr -v

```
PKCS #10 Certificate Request (Version 1.0)
Subject: CN=host, OU=Unknown, O=Unknown, L=Unknown, ST=Unknown, C=Unknown
Public Key: X.509 format RSA key
```

Extension Request:

```
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
DNSName: host.domain.com
IPAddress: 1.2.3.4
```

Again, so far so good.  The CSR does indeed contain the SAN information.

I am next using keytool to change the keystore into a .p12 keystore:

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my.keystore -srcstorepass (keystore password) -srckeypass (keystore password) -destkeystore my.keystore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12 -srcalias mydomain -deststorepass (keystore password) -destkeypass (keystore password)

This seems to work, as once again, I do a list -v -keystore my.keystore.p12:

Extensions:

```
#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
SubjectAlternativeName [
DNSName: my.domain.com
IPAddress: 1.2.3.4
```

Next step is where I suspect a problem, but I couldn't find much detail about what I might be missing.  I'm using OpenSSL to export the private key:

openssl pkcs12 -in wasp.keystore.p12 -passin pass:(keystore password) -nocerts -out my.key -passout pass:(keystore password)

Then finally I use OpenSSL to generate a 2048-bit self-signed certificate:

openssl req -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -key wasp.key -in my.csr -out my.cer

When I view the resulting my.cer certificate, it does NOT contain the Subject Alternative Name.  It's just not there.

What have I missed?

Comment: 'My ultimate goal is to generate a CSR using keytool and then use that CSR to generate a self-signed certificate using OpenSSL' why? You can generate a self-signed certificate with the `keytool` (as a matter of fact you already have), and you don't need a CSR for a self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are trying to achieve some thing different from what `keytool` has to offer, `keytool` has the ability to create a self-signed certificate. You could add the extensions while you generate the key pair. The keytool will have to generate a self-signed certificate anyway, because that's how a key pair will have to be stored in a keystore (a Private Key associated with its Certificate Chain(s)).

So technically you already have a self-signed certificate. All you could do is export that certificate by using the `-exportcert` command.

> keytool -exportcert -keystore KEYSTORE -storepass PASSWORD -alias ALIAS > ALIAS.crt

`keytool` will add your extensions in your self-signed certificate.

Answer (score 1):

First, you claim to be creating my.keystore.p12 but then using wasp.keystore.p12 -- those obviously wouldn't match and I assume this is a mistake.

Second, given that assumption, I don't believe there is anything wrong with the p12. Your posted commands didn't actually look at the cert in the p12 anywhere; if you do I bet you'll find it's exactly as in the JKS and includes the SAN. It's the *second* cert, created by OpenSSL and *not* in the p12 at all, that 'loses' SAN.

And that's because **`req -x509` doesn't put extensions from the CSR** in the cert. It can put extensions in the cert, but only from its configuration file, not from the CSR. The two cert-creating variants of `x509` namely `x509 -req -signkey` and `x509 -req -CA [-CAkey]` similarly ignore any extensions in the CSR and put in the cert only extensions provided by explicitly specified `-extfile`. The only OpenSSL commandline operation that puts extensions in a cert *from the CSR* is `ca` -- and then only if the configuration is changed to set `copy_extensions` to `copy` or `copyall` as described on the man page.

Note that if you just want a key plus selfsigned cert in PEM, OpenSSL can do that much more easily than having Java generate the key; having OpenSSL put SAN in the cert is a little harder, but there are about a dozen existing Qs on that you could find if you looked. If you want them in P12, that's also easy. And Java since at least j6 can use a P12 as a keystore without needing any JKS if the program is configurable, and since 8u60 even if not.